# Protect files from an external call

Tags: php, flash, apache-flex, zend-framework, .htaccess

I've got a Zend Framework project with an admin area. In the admin area is a Adobe Flex (Flash) application to create, save and open pdf files. The pdfs are stored in http://localhost/public/pdf/.
Is it possible that only the flex application (logged admin) has the permission to open the generated pdf files?
How can i protected the files from a direct external browser call eg. through http://localhost/public/pdf/mysecret.pdf

Does anyone have an idea/script?

Answer (score 0):

Use your web server to limit access to those files?  I mean, this is very basic web functionality.  Have you done your research?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a data access layer - programmatic script implemented by both the Flex application and server.  Basically, a service call.

You indicate there is user management, as you are logged in as Admin.

Using that authentication, your Flex app would make a service call passing needed tokens for security.  Your Zend PHP service would read the PDF from the local file system, and pass the data to the Flex client if authenticated.

"All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection" - Butler Lampson